# Operation of Subtraction and write the result in the shared preferences

Tags: android

I have a preference in the string (A) with a value of 20, I need to subtract the value of an int (B) ranging from 0 to 20, 
I tried so

```
String A = prefs.getString(A, "20");
int B=intent.getIntExtra(trn+".Intb", 0);

TextView tvRest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtrest);        
        tvRest.setText(A -(B));
```

I need to display the result of AB in the `TextView` `txtrest`, as I do.

You can write C eventually find in the preferences instead of the initial value of A after obtaining the result.

Comment: So, you want to subtract an **int** from a **String**?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like below,

```
int A = Integer.ParseInt(prefs.getString(A, "20"));
int B=intent.getIntExtra(trn+".Intb", 0);
int C=A-B;

TextView tvRest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtrest);
tvRest.setText(String.valueOf(C));
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(C)` or `Integer.toString(C)` would be cleaner than `"" + C`

Comment: @Joffrey: Thanks for the suggestion.I have edited accordingly.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking the comment into account. This now saves a `StringBuilder` allocation.

Comment: Okay, just one more thing, if I wanted to write the result in the shared preference and change it with what I had originally?

Comment: @user3564888: Edit your question accordingly with clear explanation.

Comment: You can write the value of C in the preferences instead of the initial value of A after obtaining the result.

Comment: I noticed that every time I start the class, the operation is performed again, is there a way to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: @user3564888: I couldn't get your point buddy.Could you please explain a little bit more ?

Comment: I opened another post where I explain better my problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347248/how-not-to-repeat-a-mathematical-operation