# How not to repeat a mathematical operation

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I can not find a way to avoid repeating a subtraction operation every time you restart the application, in practice, I have this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int giornispett = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(GIORNISPETT, "24"));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stats);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String trn=getPackageName();
    int Giorni=intent.getIntExtra(trn+".Intgiorni", 0);
    int Giorniresidui=giornispett-Giorni;


    TextView tvgiorni=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtgiorni);        
    tvgiorni.append(+Giorni+"");


    TextView tvGiorni_rest=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtGiorni_rest);        
    tvGiorni_rest.setText(""+Giorniresidue);
```

where I do a subtraction to a value drawn from the shared preference that will automatically update with the result of the operation, such as when initially I'm 20, I add a record to the database on and I find myself in the shared preference value 19.Se however riaccedo to the database again , the operation is repeated and the shared prference instead of 19 to 18 are taken. 
Is there a way to avoid a repeat the operation every time I log in to the database
  or better yet, if you increase days, but if I decrease subtracts the days again increases the value of days payable

```
String str1 = Integer.toString(Giorniresidui);

        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(GIORNISPETT, str1);
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: how and when do you save this value into the database or shared preferences?

Comment: I added to the post the way unless the new value in the preferences

Comment: what changes this value ?

Comment: daily starting value is changed according to what I put in the database, I thought maybe I could fix with a function if else, in practice if the value of the reopening of Activity il valore giornispett-Giorni and equal to the value of the shared preference to do nothing if the value is different perform the task, do you think that might work? but imposed as the code?